# Can not open scheme url (tel: for example) in a Crosswalk project

Tags: trigger.io

In a Crosswalk project compiled using trigger.io service, links with "tel:" scheme calls don't work anymore.

```
<a href:"tel:01223344">Call Me</a>
```

If I don't use Crosswalk compile but normal Android run mode, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Crosswalk team are currently working on this, see:

https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6690